# How do you do server side processing in a React app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I'm writing my first Node/React/Express/Next app.

I'm uncertain how to execute server side code when a request comes in.

When there's a request, I need to get some data off the server disk.  I'm trying to do this from a javascript file in my pages directory, but the 'fs' module is not accessible from here.  I guess that's because the browser must be executing the code (which is confusing for me because I thought next.js meant the server was processing the code and exporting the html back).

I've done much googling about this problem and can't seem to find an answer.  Which is bizarre, because this must be one of the most basic requirements of a web app.  Maybe the solution is so basic and I'm just overlooking the obvious?

Can anyone provide a brief explanation or pointers in the right direction on how to do server-side processing (eg reading a file from the servers disk) from a /pages/xxx.js file in a React/Express/Next app?  Or in other words, how or where do I access the 'fs' module?

The error I get is "ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in /pages

thanks

Comment: next.js is server-side *rendering* of pages, it just renders as much of your client app as possible. It doesn't have access to most back-end stuff because that still needs to be handled by your api server.

It just does some of the work your browser would be doing before handing it back off to your browser.

Comment: learn rest API, it is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Your next.js app is split in two pieces, the part running on the client *and* server (rendering the pages to HTML) and the part running only on the server (finding the pages and exposing them over HTTP).

What you want to do is possible *only on the server* and usually done in the realm of `express`, the routing framework. Next.js is designed to make it easy to create SPAs that **do not need a backend** but want server-side rendering.

However it does allow modifying the server-only component, if you need to. The documentation for that can be found in the ["Custom Server and Routing" section of the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/#custom-server-and-routing).

You can then add API routes that the front-end can call to request data form the backend, e.g. by returing JSON that the app can store in the React state.